# How do you distinguish euristically using a phase-space diagram if a point is asymptoticaly stable or not? (Using a SI model as example)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

**In my notes the following SI model is given**

$\frac{d}{dt}S(t)=(1-S(t))-R_0I(t)S(t)$

$\frac{d}{dt}I(t)=R_0I(t)S(t)$

$S(t)+I(t)=1$

$t \ge 0, R_0 >0$, $ 0 \le S(t)\le 1$, $ 0 \le I(t)\le 1$ where $S(T)$ is the fraction if Susceptible individuals and $I(t)$ the fraction of Infected Individuals
We want to study the the stability euristically using the phase space  if $R_0 >1$

**Solution:**

The equilibrium points are $(\bar u_1, \bar v_1)=(1,0)$
and  $(\bar u_2, \bar v_2)=(1/R_0,1-1/R_0)$ if $R_0 >1$

Let $f(S(t),I(t))=(1-S(t))-R_0I(t)S(t)$ and $g(S(t),I(t))= (1-S(t))-R_0I(t)S(t)$

We are interested in the region $(u,v)\in \mathscr S $ with $\mathscr S=[0,1]\times[0,1]$

There is one vertical-tangent nullcline : $I=\frac{1}{R_0S}(1-S)$

and two  horizontal-tangent nullclines: $S=\frac{1}{R_0}$ and $I=0$

then we analyse the signs of $f$ and $g$

$f(S,I)>0 $ if  $0 <I <\frac{1}{R_0S}(1-S)$

$f(S,I)<0 $ if  $\frac{1}{R_0S}(1-S)<I<1$

$g(S,I)<0 $ if  $ 0<S<\frac{1}{R_0}$

$g(S,I)>0 $if $\frac{1}{R_0}<S<1$

The phase-space diagram that we obtain with this information is the following:

[image]

and then they conclude that $(\bar u_1, \bar v_1)$ is unstable and $(\bar u_2, \bar v_2)$ is asymptotically stable. I agree on the fist one  since some arrows are leaving the point, but how can you deduce that for the second one? I don't think this plot is enough to decide.

Besides two example trajectories where provided:

[image]

But there is no explanation on how to get them , I might  as well think that $(\bar u_2, \bar v_2)$ is a center point, why should it be asymptotically stable?

**So how does one determine euristically that $(\bar u_2, \bar v_2)$ is in fact asymptotically stable and not for instance a center point?  I already proved it analyzing the eigenvalues of the jacobian so I know this must be like that, but I am interested in the euristic procedure based only on the phase-space diagram. I don't know much about sketching other that the procedure provided in this example and I don't know if there is a way to get the expression for the trajectories in order to understand they are in fact converging to $(\bar u_2, \bar v_2)$.**

Comment: The diagram alone does not provide a proof. Even if you checked the eigenvalues of the linearization at the equilibrium, it still does not justify the figure you gave. To complete a proof, you need to make sure that there are no closed orbits (limit cycles). In this particular case it can be done by using an appropriate Lyapunov function.